# C++ comparing point numbers

Tags: c++, double, operators, equals

my lecturer told me that in C++ it is not true to compare double numbers with the operator `==`, but if that is true how could I compare them correctly, and why this method isn't accurate?

**Edit**, I think that they are equal if the difference is too small but what if I want to know if they are exactly the same number? which method do programmers of big companies implement?

**Note: My question isn't a duplicate, I have many other small details which are not mentioned there.**

Comment: It is not correct, but it is partially correct.  The `==` will compare for an exact match.  Some math operations can have tiny rounding differences, and those tiny differences means that there is not an exact match.  So for situations that there may be tiny rounding differences, it may be better to check for a tolerance range instead of an exact match.

Comment: could you give an example for: "Some math operations can have tiny rounding differences" So in general I should stick with == if I don't use these operations?

Comment: Example:  `1.0 + 2.0 == 3.0` will be exact, and yield `true`.  `1.0/3.0 + 1.0/3.0 + 1.0/3.0 == 1.0` may have tiny rounding differences on the left side such that they do not equal, so yields `false`.  The rule is:  if you only use whole numbers and only do addition, subtraction, and multiplication, you should be okay with `==` exact comparisons.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I ran the following and it printed true     if (0.1*10==1)
    std::cout << "True" << std::endl;

Comment: Why do you need to know if they are exactly the same? You mention there are details that does not make this a duplicate - I'd suggest mentioning those details here.

Comment: Your test doesn't mean it works always: also depends on compiler optimzation, processor architecture, etc.